# Spring MVC - How to connect controller with service class and DAO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm learning about DAO and Services and I tried to make an very simple web app for some tests (JSP). I created DAO and Service classes, but how can I make them cooperate with each other? I want in order to value entered in textfield will be saved in my database. Here is a code:

StudentDAO:

```
public void create(Student student);
```

StudentDAOImpl:

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

DataSource dataSource;

public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    return jdbcTemplate;
}

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public void create(Student student) {
    String query = "insert into studentdb.student (`name`, `age`) values (?,?)";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, student.getName());
        ps.setString(2, student.getAge());
        int out = ps.executeUpdate();

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

StudentService looks exactly the same like StudentDAO, here is StudentServiceImpl:

```
StudentDAO studentDAO;


public void createStudent(Student student) {

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("studentconfig.xml");

    studentDAO = ctx.getBean("studentDAO", StudentDAO.class);

    student.setName(//value entered in webapp);
    student.setAge(//value entered in webapp);

    studentDAO.create(student);
}
```

And here is MainController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView homePagePost(Model model, @ModelAttribute("student") Student student1){

     model.addAttribute("student", student1);
     studentService.createStudent(student1);

    ModelAndView home = new ModelAndView("index");
    return home;
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<form action="/webapplication/home.html" method="post">
<input type="text" name="${student.name}"/>
<input type="text" name="${student.age} }"/>
<input type="submit" value="confirm!"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need DI(dependency injection), or more precisely the implementation of this - Inversion of Control.

Read about this [Spring DI](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_dependency_injection.htm) and [Spring IoC containers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_ioc_containers.htm).

Then you need indicate where you want to autowire classes into another with annotation like:

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;
```

After that you need to declare application context which classes to scan to initialize all classes and inject all dependencies like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="dao" />
```

So when you will deploy application deploy descriptor will be parsed together with application context and then scanning the packages with classes and their dependencies spring bean container will initialize all this classes by IoC principle from last to beginning injecting these one into another.

In general you need to do like this, maybe i have skipped something, but this is the principle.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned a good solution is Springs Dependency Injection.

Here is some streamlined information:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6F3Cv1a7G0w

This is your StudentDao with implementation:

```
public interface StudentDao {

}

@Component
public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {
   //TODO Your Code
}
```

This is your StudentService with implementation:

```
@Service
public interface StudentService { 

}

@Component
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

   @Autowired
   private StudentDao studentDao;

}
```

This is your StudentController with implementation:

```
@Controller
public interface StudentController { 

}

@Component
public class StudentControllerImpl implements StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

}
```

This is your Application class (if you are using SpringBoot):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.your.packages.controller", "com.your.packages.service", "com.your.packages.dao")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

@ComponentScan will tell instruct Spring to search the specified packages for class annotated with @Component, @Service, @Controller and others.